# How do you access the original request (and port) in ngnix

Tags: apache, web, nginx

I have the following network configuration:
F5 LB --> 2 NGNIX nodes --> App server

For server to server calls we sign the request based on scheme, port and uri on the source server and compare this signature on the destination by re-signing the request again based on the same parameters.
server to server calls follow this path:
source server --> F5 LB --> NGNIX --> destination server.

The original request sent by the source server is sent to https without port, and thus signed without port (or using default port for that matter). 
LB adds custom port to the request and pass it to NGNIX. NGNIX in turn is configured to pass the server scheme, host and port with the request to the app server:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
```

The destination server received the port coming from the LB instead of the one sent with the original request sent by the source server, ending up failing the signature check on the destination server.
The same was tested with Apache, using ajp with the proxied servers and the request passed is holding the original port, not the one added by the LB.

After thorough reading, it comes up to a simple question:
**How do you access the original request (and port) in ngnix?**

Here's the rest of the relevant configuration:

**proxy.conf:**

```
proxy_redirect          off;
client_max_body_size      10m;
client_body_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_connect_timeout   90;
proxy_send_timeout      90;
proxy_read_timeout      90;
proxy_buffers           32 4k;
proxy_buffer_size       8k;
proxy_http_version      1.0;
proxy_set_header        Host $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

**configuration**

```
log_format upstreamlog '[$time_local] $remote_addr $status "$request" $body_bytes_sent - $server_name to: $upstream_addr $upstream_response_time sec "$http_user_agent"';

server {

listen       9080;
listen       9443 ssl;
server_name  myserver.com;

root html;

error_log /data/server_openresty/error.log info;
access_log /ldata/server_openresty/logs/access.log upstreamlog;

gzip on;
gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/xhtml+xml application/xml;

ssl_certificate         /data/server_openresty/nginx/certs/dev_wildCard.crt;
ssl_certificate_key     /code/server_openresty/nginx/certs/dev_wildCard.key;
ssl_protocols           SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers             HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5;

### headers passed to the proxies
proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;

location /api/serverA{
    proxy_pass  http://serverA-cluster;
}

location /api/serverB{
    proxy_pass  http://serverB-cluster;
}
```

}

Comment: would you mind posting the whole config of nginx (anonymized, of course) here?

Comment: I take it you have no control over the source server? Then you have to solve it in your LB. She's the only one that had access to the original port and as such the ability to pass it on.

Comment: @Melvyn, I have control on both source and destination server.
Meddling with the LB is not something I'm keen to do, it should remain logic free. What's not clear to me, is how Apache was able to pass the original request to the destination, taking aside the LB intervention. I would like to do the same with ngnix.

Comment: Take a look at the headers arriving at the nginx node. Is there a header in there containing the forwarded port? Perhaps the LB injects it and it's dropped by nginx for reasons not clear from the terse config or it's replaced as its passing it on.

Comment: Is there a way to print out all headers?
I'm using $header_<name> to print out single header

Comment: That aside, same configuration, with the same LB working with Apache web server did not cause losing the original request. I can only assume that nginx supports such configuration having several nginx nodes behind LB

Comment: Tcpdump is your friend.

Comment: Does LB set X-Forwarded-Host or something like that?

Comment: @gross I'm in the process of analyzing tcpdumps logs, figured that I better understand what does the LB pass to nginx. Thanks for the lead, I'll search for it.